# Having trouble coding RMI client callback from server - UnmarshalException ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, callback, client-server, rmi

I will try to keep this post as small as possible so I will add more information and code if requested.

Scenario: I am writing a server/client application to track some of our processes here in the company, so the user will create small tags that will go from one user's screen to another (clients written in Swing) according to the workflow.

I am running a local Glasfish 3.1 server (in Eclipse) and MySql. On the server I am running Spring MVC and Spring Data + Hibernate.

A property file holds this information for easy change:

```
rmi.serverPort = 1971
rmi.clientPort = 2010
```

During the server start up there's a bean that sets the RMI environment like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private RmiData rmiData;
  @Autowired
  private DataRequestHandler dataRequestHandler;
  @Autowired
  private ConnectionRequestHandler connectionRequestHandler;
  .
  .
  .

  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiData.getServerPort());
  String rmiUrl = "rmi://" + rmiData.getHost() + ":" + rmiData.getServerPort() + "/";
  Naming.rebind(rmiUrl + "ConnectionRequestHandler", connectionRequestHandler);
  Naming.rebind(rmiUrl + "DataRequestHandler", dataRequestHandler);
```

**The server contains the interfaces and implementations of both handlers and the client has only the interfaces.**

This is working with no SecurityManager and no Policy file. Although I had to include the Hibernate jars into the client to solve other exceptions (solution found here on SO).

After making the client connecting to the server and requesting data work, I started to code the callback to the client (the server will have to push data to the client as well). So this is where I am stuck now.

Here is how I am making the callback (the client acts like a server):

```
  private ClientCallbackHandler clientCallbackHandler = new ClientCallbackHandlerImpl();
  .
  .
  .

  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiData.getClientPort());
  String rmiUrl = "rmi://localhost:" + rmiData.getClientPort() + "/";
  Naming.rebind(rmiUrl + "ClientCallbackHandler", clientCallbackHandler);
```

**The server contains only the client interface and the client has both the interface and implementation of the handler.**

So when the server performs

```
  String rmiUrl = "rmi://" + clientHost + ":" + clientPort + "/";
  clientCallbackHandler = (ClientCallbackHandler)Naming.lookup(rmiUrl + "ClientCallbackHandler");
```

I get the following exception **ON THE SERVER:**

```
  SEVERE: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.affair.socontrol.rmi.ClientCallbackHandlerImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I am avoiding installing the SecurityManager and Policy file (also tried that with no success) and I am stuck right here.

I cannot understand why is the server complaining about the implementation class once all it needs is the interface. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for several hours I finally found the problem.

The ClientCallbackHandlerImpl class **WAS NOT extending** *UnicastRemoteObject*.
After that the code ran smoothly. Thank you who read the post and thought about something.

PS: I know it looks like a noob's fault but I avoid doing code copy/paste.

Comment: Moral: don't do copy/paste. Understand what you're doing.

Comment: Actually I copy/paste my own code in a few cases only and no one can work with rmi by copying some one else's code. I do understand what Im doing but this class extension skipped my eyes. My biggest problem here was actually NOT copying code from other classes. Thanks for coming by.

Comment: For completeness, you could also have called `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` in the constructor instead of extending `UnicastRemoteObject().`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The examples ou there are very poor and all of them extend UnicastRemoteObject. Will learn more about this one, thanks again!